# Is there a one line function for generating a Sawtooth wave?

Tags: c#

I am new to signal processing, and I am trying to create a function that generates a Sawtooth wave in C#, I have already made a Triangle wave function but I am not sure how to make it as a sawtooth function using a period and an amplitude (Max - Min)

Triangle wave function

```cs
public static float Triangle(float time, float min, float max, float period, float noise)
{
    return (float)(Math.Abs(max - min) / period * (period - Math.Abs((time % (2 * period)) - period)) + min)
}
```

Comment: You mean instead of `/\/\ ` you want `/)/)`?

Comment: @Rafalon Yes instead of /\ i want /|

Comment: What if you remove that `2 *` in `time % (2 * period)`? Entering that formula in Wolfram Alpha seems to give a `//` pattern (you'll obviously never get that vertical line)

Comment: code seems incomplete and doesn't compile

Comment: Triangle itself can be reduced to: `max + (min - max) * Math.Abs(time / period % 2.0 - 1.0)`

Comment: @Rafalon Yes it does work, but it does not reach the max

Comment: @haidarDif with functions you can only reach one in `(min, max)`, as when you reach the `|`, the function can only return either `min` or `max`, not both

Comment: @Rafalon What i meant was that it does not reach the specified max value before dropping to Min Value, example Min = 200 and Max = 500,  here it starts from 200 but it reaches only 495 before going back to 200 again

Comment: Well this obviously depends on the steps size... The smaller the steps, the closer you can go to max, though as already said, you will never reach it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a sawtooth, just take the remainder of division by the period.

```
static double Fract(double t)
{
    return t % 1.0;
}
```

Assuming you want this to work for negative `t` as well, this would be better:

```
static double Fract(double t)
{
    return t - Math.Floor(t);
}
```

Scale the function to match the desired period and output range:

```
static double Sawtooth(double t, double period, double min, double max)
{
    return min + (max - min) * Fract(t / period);
}
```

Comment: This works, the only problem is it does not Reach the Max value, it goes down before that

Comment: Correct, and for a 'pure' sawtooth, that is inevitable. At the 'drop', the signal instantaneously goes from max to min, but being a function, it can only be one or the other at that very moment in time. A solution could be to use a continuous function instead; one with a drop that is steep but not vertical. That could either be an asymmetric triangle wave, or a [smooth sawtooth](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2943506). It all depends on how you are going to use it. I have no experience with signal processing, but I guess a continuous function is more representative for real-world processes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, just to make sure are you saying that a sawtooth wave can never reach the max value?

Comment: Well, you could mirror `Fract`, making it reach max, but it will no longer reach min. Or you could slightly distort the sawtooth and 'flatten' the peaks; feels like cheating as it is no longer a 'real' sawtooth. (But then again, neither are the continuous functions I proposed earlier.) I don't know if either of this will work for you. Please explain, why is it so important that max is reached? It will only be for an infinitesimal period of time; in the physical world, the fact cannot even be measured; it would require the quantity of an entity to be measured at an infinite sample rate.